# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". Preference node "org.eclipse.wst.validation" has been removed

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to open my Maven project with Eclipse Juno, but I'm getting this error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
>   Preference node "org.eclipse.wst.validation" has been removed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 74):

**Same probleme here, there the solution I fix it**

- Open the `.project` file with your prefered text editor.
- delete the  node that is about "org.eclipse.wst.validation"
- Close your project
- Open your project
- Launch Maven Update...

Should be good.

**Another way to fix it, if you don't want to change your .project config**
(or if you had several projects that must be fixed)

- Close your workspace (or eclipse)

-move out `<WorkspaceDir>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects` from the workspace directory

-reopen you workspace

- close it again

-move back the .projects dir (say yes to replace questions ? )

- open you workspace
- Launch Maven Update

Should be good

Comment: If you can't see the org.eclipse.wst.validation node. Then close the project. Open it back and do maven update project. It should be fixed.

Comment: Worked for me ,I Did your first option for all the projects which has the maven Update problem.In addition the "org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs" file contains in ".settings" folder of Project directory.

Comment: Thanks Akshay.. Same issue solved for me as per your answer.

Comment: In Mars, Neon, etc, this step is not needed.  Simply close and reopen the IDE.

Comment: In eclipse Neon, running it using the "-clean" parameter did the trick for me.

Answer (score 33):

Simpler fix:

- Close Project
- Open Project
- Project > Clean
- Run Maven Update

Comment: This should be the answer, because it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I was using Eclipse Mars and in my case, just close and reopen my IDE did the work.

Comment: Same thing in Eclipse Neon.  It seems that in newer versions of IDE, merely closing and reopening does it.  Hopefully, in newerer versions still to come, even that will not be required. :-)

Comment: Same here in STS, restarted, then Maven->Update Project and all was fine
(Did not have to delete anything from the .project file)

Answer (score 3):

Dont know, if you still have this problem, but here is the solution worked for me:

> It appears that deleting the file org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs in
>   the directory .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
>   (default settings for workspace) or .settings in each individual
>   project will cause the settings for validation to be reset to their
>   original settings.  You can then use validation without getting error
>   messages and try resetting the options from there.  However, I'm not
>   sure what combination of settings would cause the problem to reappear.
>   However, if it does, you can repeat the process.

got this from here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355012

in my case i didnt have the mentioned file in this folder, but i had a bunch of other org.eclipse.wst.* files. deleting them all did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to the `.projects` folder as mentioned in another answer.
The solution is to add a file called `org.eclipse.wst.validation.prefs` in the `.settings` folder. This will restore the eclipse validation node.

The content of the file, depending on your eclipse version, might look like this:

```
disabled=06target
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution is too simple , deleting .project file then clean the project and maven update will success surely

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one error that could be caused by multiple different sources.  I just had the same error however, and just figured out why.  In my situation, I just tried to force update some code by deleting a few temporary files.  Turned out I accidentally deleted that file as well.  I thankfully had it under source control, so I pulled the file back and updated the project with Maven.  I also made sure any other errors were fixed so that the project would clean / update successfully.

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but I hope it helps!  Good luck!